# How do I get a group by with the last record added?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

**Members**

```
m_id | name | email       | mobile     | type | is_Approved | is_status
1    | nbvg |as@gmail.com | 9876543212 | 1    |     1       | 1
2    | svfs |cd@gmail.com | 1233123121 | 2    |     1       | 1
3    | aasd |sv@gmail.com | 1233123121 | 2    |     1       | 1
4    | pokg |pk@gmail.com | 1233123121 | 2    |     1       | 1
```

**membership_details**

```
   r_id  | m_id | duration  | date_of_added
    1    | 1    | 2018-2019 | 2018-04-01 07:01:16
    2    | 2    | 2018-2019 | 2018-04-01 13:11:53
    3    | 1    | 2019-2020 | 2019-02-02 02:15:45
    4    | 3    | 2018-2019 | 2018-04-01 20:30:10
```

Below code, I am using in the model.

```
$get_s_member = array('members.type' =>2,'members.is_Approved'=>1,'members.is_status'=>1);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('members'); 
        $this->db->join('membership_details', 'members.m_id = membership_details.m_id','LEFT');
        $this->db->where($get_s_member);
        $this->db->group_by('membership_details.m_id'); 
        $this->db->order_by('membership_details.date_of_added','DESC');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result   = $query->result();
       // print_r($result);
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
     if($result)
    {
         return $result;  
    }
    else 
    {
       return 0;  
    }
```

**sql query**

```
SELECT *
FROM `members`
LEFT JOIN `membership_details` ON `members`.`m_id` = `membership_details`.`m_id`
WHERE `members`.`type` = 2
AND `members`.`is_Approved` = 1
AND `members`.`is_status` = 1
GROUP BY `membership_details`.`m_id`
ORDER BY `membership_details`.`date_of_added` DESC
```

Just notice in the membership_details table there are some duplicate m_id. SO I tried using group by m_id and desc to get the last number of the records but I am not getting it I am getting the first record. but I am getting 2 and 3 are desc order.

How do I get a group by with the last record added?

My expected output is,

```
   m_id|name
     1 |nbvg   | 2019-2020 | 2019-02-02 02:15:45
     3 |aasd   | 2018-2019 | 2018-04-01 20:30:10
     2 |svfs   | 2018-2019 | 2018-04-01 13:11:53
     4 |pokg   |           |
```

Comment: @Shadow, Yes, I checked that also. but not working...what column I have to use with max? max(membership_details.date_of_added)?

Comment: You need to use that column with max by which you want to get the most recent record in a group.

Comment: I tried max(membership_details.m_id) but same issue I am getting.

Comment: Then you have made a mistake in implementing the solutions in the duplicate question.

Comment: @Shadow, That's the reason I asked the question.